# UPDATE: (I need to run testrpc before running the code) Problem with signing a message with "web3.eth.personal.sign" or "web3.eth.sign"

Tags: web3js, accounts, addresses, signature, password

I use exactly the example of `web3js` ([here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#id17)) to sign a text.

So, I generated a `.js` file asfollows :

```
Web3 = require("web3")
web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

web3.eth.personal.sign("Hello world", "0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe", "test password!")
.then(console.log);
```

However, I receive the following error message, when I run this file with Terminal (Ubuntu) as follows : node filename.js

Error message: https://ibb.co/j6HEUy

[image]

Even when I use `web3.eth.sign` instead of `web3.eth.personal.sign`, I receive the same error message :

> **Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""**

UPDATE: I need to run `testrpc` before running the code. However, now I receive another error message as follows:

> **Error: Returned error: Error: cannot sign data; no private key**

[image]

Comment: Hi @sas, did you figure out a solution?

Comment: @fabdarice Hi, apparently I must use MetaMask to sign a message, instead of using testRPC.